# firebase notification cordova ios integration

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to add firebase notifications on cordova app ios but i can't.
This are the steps i've done:

1-created the firebase project
2-copy the configuration file Googleservice-info.plist
3-install cordova plugin fcm
4-add this code in file index.js

```
window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission();


    FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
        if(data.wasTapped){
          //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
          console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
        }else{
          //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
          console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
        }
    });

    FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic(topicSub);
```

5-installed cocoapods
6-executed this command:

```
pod init
```

7-in file PodFile i've inserted this code:

```
pod ’Firebase/Core’

pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

8-installed pod with this comand:

```
pod install
```

10-open the project with .xcworkspace file

Now xcode return me this errors:

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

hey you need install this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support --save
```

This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run below code to update:

step1: pod repo update

step2: pod install

This may work.